# How to specify remote MSMQ queue name when configuring rebus routing?

Tags: msmq, rebus

I've seen examples using "queueName@machineName" when specifying a destination address but I'm having problems with it.

> .Routing(r => r.TypeBased().Map(typeof(Job), "consumer.input@othermachine"))

With this format, I get the following exception:

"Invalid queue path name."

Am I using the right format or is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rebus 0.98.8 had a bug in its MSMQ transport that would not format remote addresses properly. Moreover, it would fail when using IP addresses instead of machine names.

Version 0.98.9 (which is on NuGet.org in a few minutes) fixes this, which means that you can now properly address remote queues like this:

```
someQueue@someOtherMachine
```

or

```
someQueue@172.10.20.30
```

Thanks for bringing it to my attention! I guess it shows that I'm using Azure Service Bus for most of my stuff these days ;)

Comment: Great!  Will try first thing tomorrow!  Thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks again